# Does grafana variables refresh only with F5?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

When I do Prometheus query in grafana, I use a label `"date`" as a filter. For example I need to query `my_data{date="2023-10-30"}`. This query shows exactly values of `my_data` today.

[image]

I make the label as a grafana variable with refresh option as When `on dashboard load`. Note that only when the real date is `2023-10-30`, the metric with label `date="2023-10-30"` exists, and variable query `labe_values(my_data, date)` returns a `"2023-10-30"` value.

[image]

So suppose I open the dashboard at 2023-10-30 and display it on my screen. On the second day(2023-10-31) I need to manually click F5 and reload the dashboard to let grafana variable can get a label value 2023-10-31, and then I can use it in the PromQL. This is really annoying.

My question is if the grafana variable can auto query the label values without F5, or if there is some other tricks to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, dashboard load is triggered by F5 or reload symbol in the top right corner.

Additionally, variable will be updated if value of the variable it depends on has changed, regardless of the update configuration. But this is not useful for this problem.

So, in your situation I'd say only manual refresh can be used.

---

In general, storing date in the label is not recommended:it increases cardinality of metrics significantly.

Additionally, your description leads me to believe that this label is always equal to current date,and if so thisis redundant: all metrics have timestamp of scraping attached, and thus date can be extracted automatically. Consider dropping this label from your label.

Comment: thanks a lot! The metric is more like a house price. One house could have a price on 2023-10-30 and another price on 2023-10-31. So currently we need both price recorded by this metric with different label `date`. Anyway, we got your idea about the inconvenience and would consider a better way carefully.